# Does a description or specification exist for scala picked signatures?

Tags: scala

I'm looking to pull some data out of the pickled signatures of classes stored on disk, but not loaded in the jvm.

Getting hold of the byte array stored in the ScalaSignature is easy enough via ASM, it is however less than clear how it should be interpreted.

The closest I can find to a description of the format is

http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sid/10

Which doesn't describe it at all.

Does a better resource exist, or is my only option to delve into the source?

Comment: you delved into attached pdf, right?

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes. It provides enough info for me to get a PickleBuffer, but no guidance on how to extract useful information from it.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my own question I've now found this, dated 2008, which looks to provide a good overview :-

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.214.5115&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Would be interested in any more recent documents.